# Best way to show a loading spinner/gif while my React component is fetching via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Imagine I have a very simple React component that shows a list of elements that are stored in `this.state.myList` (see example below)

Hitting a "Refresh" button at the bottom causes React to query the backend server and retrieve an updated list that it will then display. The actual contents or implementation of this list are irrelevant.

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  handleButtonClick: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/some/refresh/url",
      data: JSON.stringify({}),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: (function(response){
        self.setState({ myList: response.list });
      })
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.myList.map(function(item) {
              return <li id="{item.id}">{item.name}</li>
            });
          }
        </ul>

        <input type="submit" value="REFRESH LIST" onClick={this.handleButtonClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Let's say the AJAX call (for whatever reason) takes a few seconds. In that meantime, I'd love to show a standard "loading" or "spinner" gif to let the user know it's working.

What's the best approach to doing that here?

- Right before the AJAX call I could manually update the DOM and insert a spinner gif but that doesn't seem like the "React way to do it". And plus I don't know what impact that would have on the ReactDOM that react maintains.
- I could track a state for `isLoading` and show the spinner instead of the list if it is loading. But then I would need it to `render()` something and then immediately kick off another call to an AJAX action.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way I always solve this is for the component to track `fetchInProgress` in its state.

Before you make your fetch, you set this value to `true`; when the fetch completes (either success or fail), you set the value back to `false`.

The component's `render` method then honors this flag; if the flag is `true`, it renders a spinner instead of a dataset.

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
    handleButtonClick: function() {

        // before making call, set fetch flag
        self.setState({ fetchInProgress: true });

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/some/refresh/url",
            data: JSON.stringify({}),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: (function(response) {
                // when updating with dataset, also reset fetch flag
                self.setState({
                    fetchInProgress: false,
                    myList: response.list
                });
            }),
            failure: ((function(reason) {
                // make sure to reset even if fetch fails!
                self.setState({
                    fetchInProgress: false
                });
            })
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.state.fetchInProgress
                            : <Spinner />
                            : this.state.myList.map(function(item) {
                                    return <li id="{item.id}">{item.name}</li>
                                })
                    }
                </ul>

                <input type="submit" value="REFRESH LIST" onClick={this.handleButtonClick} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach is great for simple scenarios, we created a helper library to avoid having to manually toggle the fetchInProgress flag,  and handle multiple requests launched from several places, hope it helps:  https://github.com/Lemoncode/react-promise-tracker a post about how it works: https://www.basefactor.com/react-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-on-fetch-calls

Comment: Thank you for the solution, That worked for me very well

Answer (score 4):

The React model is built around having UI as a representation of your state. That means you should model your state as "what is the necessary data" and the return value of `render()` is just how you display that data.

In your case, you should keep track of `isLoading` and in `render()` you conditionally display the spinner based on the value in your state.

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {isLoading: false};
  },
  handleButtonClick: function() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/some/refresh/url",
      data: JSON.stringify({}),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: (function(response){
        self.setState({ myList: response.list, isLoading: false });
      })
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.myList.map(function(item) {
              return <li id="{item.id}">{item.name}</li>
            });
          }
        </ul>

        {this.state.isLoading && <Spinner />}

        <input type="submit" value="REFRESH LIST" onClick={this.handleButtonClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense

Answer (score 4):

small edit from @Tom's answer above.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.fetchInProgress ?
                        <Spinner />
                    :
                        this.state.myList.map(function(item) {
                            return <li id="{item.id}">{item.name}</li>
                        })
                }
            </ul>

            <input type="submit" value="REFRESH LIST" onClick={this.handleButtonClick} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Next time just leave a comment

Comment: Will do! When I gain my right to comment everywhere :) Thanks!