# Undefined is Not an Object (evaluating 'this.state.data.confirmed.value')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and practicing by creating a project which makes requests from a COVID-19 API. However, when I run my code, I get this error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data.confirmed.value')

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class TrackerScreen extends React.Component {
   state = {
      data: ''
   }
   componentDidMount = () => {
      fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);
         this.setState({
            data: responseJson
         })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text>
               {this.state.data.confirmed.value}
            </Text>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default TrackerScreen;
```

I converted my componentDidMount to an arrow function as suggested by other members on an old thread but that did not get rid of the error. Does anybody have a solution to this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to show a loading spinner/gif while my React component is fetching via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359683/best-way-to-show-a-loading-spinner-gif-while-my-react-component-is-fetching-via)

Comment: `{this.state?.data?.confirmed?.value ?? ''}` check optional chaining in JS maybe also Nullish coalescing operator

Answer (score 0):

The first render will happen before the componentDidMount will be called. So, during the first render the data property from your state will be an empty string. And the code inside the render function is trying to access a nested prop. Either provide a more described state, like:

```
   state = {
      data: { confirmed: { value: null } }
   }
```

or check the value inside the render function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class TrackerScreen extends React.Component {
   state = {
      data: ''
   }
   componentDidMount = () => {
      fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);
         this.setState({
            data: responseJson
         })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });
   }
   render() {
      const { data: {confirmed: { value } = { value: null } } } = this.state
      return value ? (
         <View>
            <Text>
               {value}
            </Text>
         </View>
      ): null;
   }
}
export default TrackerScreen;
```

You probably don't want to render anything if the data isn't present at the moment, so an additional check for the value will handle that

Comment: You're right, but the second example won't work as it is right now.

Comment: works for me:
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-violet-cyl49?file=/src/App.js

Comment: oh yeah, it works, but only because `''.confirmed === undefined`, the initial `state` shouldn't be a string.

Comment: agree, an empty string will act as `undefined` during the destructuring operation, so the default value will be applied. I mentioned that it will be much better to provide a correctly formatted object as an initial state value